# GoLang - How to Execute/Spawn a process as 'Hidden'

Tags: go

This may only pertain to Windows, but I want to spawn a process from my GO program so that it runs hidden - the process will calculate some results and return them over stdout.  I just don't want the annoying command window to popup while it is running (it's really just a background calculation process).

How can you execute another process 'hidden'?

Thanks!

Comment: you mean that run a go program without open the cmd window?

Comment: Any command line program - could be another GO program, or anything else.  As an example - let's say I wanted a sorted list of running processes on windows, I could do this as follows:  tasklist | sort.  So from my GO program, I'd want to get the results of this operation, but not have the user have to see the command window popup and then disappear - I'd just want to wire up the stdout and receive the output strings back in the GO program once the operation completed.

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this

```
var attr os.ProcAttr 
attr.Sys.HideWindow = true
p, err := os.StartProcess("whatever", nil, &attr)
```

That sets the `STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW` flag in windows which should stop the called process opening up a cmd window.

See the [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)